# OpenGL, почему квадрат не двигается?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

const GLint WIDTH = 640, HEIGTH = 480;

const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}";



const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main () \n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"}";



int main() {

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGTH, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);
    if (nullptr == window) {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED" << infoLog << endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    GLfloat ver[]{
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ver), ver, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {


        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        ver[0] = ver[0] + 0.1;
        ver[3] = ver[3] + 0.1;
        ver[6] = ver[6] + 0.1;
        ver[9] = ver[9] + 0.1;

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 5);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое буфера на стороне GPU вы обновляете только один раз при вызове `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ver), ver, GL_STREAM_DRAW);`. Модификации `ver[0] = ver[0] + 0.1;` обновляют только содержимое локальной переменной.

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо что уделили время! а не подскажите как обновлять содержимое gpu? что бы происходило движение??

Comment: КАЖИСЬ Я ПОНЯЛ! ПРОСТО СКОПИРОВАЛ В ЦИКЛ
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ver), ver, GL_STREAM_DRAW); И ОБЪЕКТ ЗАДВИГАЛСЯ

Comment: но мне кажется то что я делаю не правильно! ведь я получается все время из оперативки загружаю данные в видеокарту.??? а нельзя как нибудь напрямую изменять значение масива загрушеного в памяти видеокарты?

Comment: @ggg3fm Вообще говоря, да, делаете вы неправильно. Обычно буфер с данными модели (который обычно большой) не изменяют, а вместо этого создают константный буфер (маленький) для использовать в вершинном шейдере и для каждого кадра изменяют этот константный буфер, а в шейдере модифицируют координаты вершин в соответствии со значением константного буфера.

Comment: получается, из большого буфера (где большое количество вершин) идет подгрузка вершин в маленький буфер? и все изменения происходят в маленьком буфере?
то есть эти строки кода говорят о загрузке в большой буфер?
 glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ver), ver, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
а маленький буфер тоже хранит значения в памяти gpu?

Comment: @ggg3fm Нет, большой буфер с вершинами не меняется. А координаты вершин меняются в вершинном шейдере на основе данных, лежащих в маленьком буфере. Почитайте любой туториал, где объясняются матрицы для преобразования вершинных координат. В вашем случае можно просто хранить в меленьком буфере требуемый сдвиг для вершин.